# Laravel 8 validation to only accept the following

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a multi select form that returns 1, 2 and 3.
I wanted to make a validation that it will only accept certain combinations such as:

```
    1
    1 & 2
    1 & 2 & 3
    2
    2 & 3
```

Any ideas how to make this work? Thank You!

My blade file

---

```
<select id="role" class="form-multiselect block mt-1 w-full" multiple name="role" required />
 <option value="1"> Role 1</option>
 <option value="2"> Role 2</option>
 <option value="3"> Role 3</option>
</select>
```

---

My validation:

```
   'role' => ['required', RULE::in(['1'])] // Tried it with just one value but now it shows selected role is invalid
```

Comment: So 1 & 3 will be regarded as invalid ?

Comment: 1 and 3, 3 will be invalid

Answer (score 1):

```
request()->validate([
    'column_name' => 'required|in:1,2,3'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but gets the job done.
Before I validate. I added this.

```
  $invalid = array('1', '3');
  $invalid2 = array('3');

if ($this->role == $invalid2) {
    $this->confirmingUserAdd = false;
    session()->flash('error', 'Cannot add');
}

if ($this->role == $invalid) {
    $this->confirmingUserAdd = false;
    session()->flash('error', 'Cannot add');
}
```